# How to identify the disks of a Linux virtual machine in VMware vSphere 6

Tags: linux, rhel, disk, vmware, scsi

I have a virtualized RHEL7 server with vsphere 6, I need to remove some virtual disks from vCenter that are presented to my virtual machine (rhel server) that are no longer being used by the operating system of the virtualized server ( rhel), but since I have several or almost all of the same size (5GB) I am worried about eliminating one that is being used, how can I identify it with total certainty without taking risks?

Comment: Is the question expecting people to guess the VmWare/storage setup?